# How many fossils are going to be sent back from the Faraway Museum?

Tags: animal-crossing

According to the Animal Crossing wiki, the museum will return only 3 fossils per day, but if you've sent more than 3 in a day the rest will be returned on other days:

> There is no limit to the amount of fossils that can be sent to the Museum in a single day. However, only three will be delivered back to the player each day, with the rest delivered on succeeding days.
>   http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Faraway_Museum

Assuming that's true, and that you can find up to 5 fossils in a day, then you can quickly build up a "backlog" of fossils. So if you send 10 fossils in two days, the museum will return only 6 in the same amount of time, then 3 more the day after and 1 final fossil after that.

There must be a maximum number of extra fossils that can be stored in that "backlog". Has anyone found out what that number is?